# react native transform view without hiding when it is outside screen

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, transform

i am new to react native. Is it possible to transform a view in a endless loop from left to right without hideing when it is outside Screen?
Like in this pictures. Like a banner which goes endless from left to right.

[image: First]

[image: Second]

....

Comment: I have Updated my Answer Logic using **react-native-swiper**  @KT Work

Answer (score 0):

You can use two same screens in **react-native-swiper** with loop, it will create endless effect

https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper

Comment: i think swiper is not the right thing. The main problem is to show the hidden part on the other side...

Comment: You can use two same screens in `react-native-swiper` with loop, it will create endless effect :/

Comment: I have Updated my Answer Logic using **react-native-swiper**  @TobiasK